# Get amount and put elsewhere

Tags: javascript

I´d like to get the amount between "(+$" and ")" and add it to the value of the inputbox.

For example, you select the following:
Solero Exotic (+$1.85)
Cappuccino (+$2.49)
iMac 27-inch 3.1GHz (+$1,999.00)

These amounts will be subtracted from the options you've selected:
1.85
2.49
1,999.00

The inputbox will display: **2003.34**

Anyone know a javascript code that can do this? (without adding more attributes to the Option tag)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Get amount and put elsewhere</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="">

  <fieldset>

    <ul style="list-style:none;padding-left:0;">
      <li>Ice Cream:
        <select class="optionsIceCream" name="IceCream">
          <option value="IceCream01">Select Ice Cream</option>
          <option value="IceCream02">Solero Exotic (+$1.85)</option>
          <option value="IceCream03">Magnum Ecuador (+$4.85)</option>
          <option value="IceCream04">Cornetto Enigma (+$2.00)</option>
        </select>
      </li>

      <li>Coffee:
        <select class="optionsCoffee" name="Coffee">
          <option value="Coffee01">Select Coffee</option>
          <option value="Coffee02">Cup of Joe (+$0.99)</option>
          <option value="Coffee03">Cappuccino (+$2.49)</option>
          <option value="Coffee04">Latte Macchiato (+$2.99)</option>
        </select>
      </li>

      <li>Computers:
        <select class="optionsComputers" name="Computers">
          <option value="Computer01">Select Computer</option>
          <option value="Computer02">Dell Inspiron 620 (+$449.99)</option>
          <option value="Computer03">HP Pavilion dv7t (+$949.99)</option>
          <option value="Computer04">iMac 27-inch 3.1GHz (+$1,999.00)</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>

    Total: <input class="totalAmount" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0.00" />

  </fieldset>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

********************************** UPDATE: 09-09-2011 **********************************

I found a solution, thanks to [Dominic H](http://answers.yahoo.com/activity?show=TxHLcJ57aa) from *Yahoo! Answers*

It's simple but very effective and it works perfectly!

Here's the entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Get amount and put elsewhere</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="">

  <fieldset>

    <ul style="list-style:none;padding-left:0;">
      <li>Ice Cream:
        <select class="optionsIceCream" name="IceCream">
          <option value="IceCream01">Select Ice Cream</option>
          <option value="IceCream02">Solero Exotic (+$1.85)</option>
          <option value="IceCream03">Magnum Ecuador (+$4.85)</option>
          <option value="IceCream04">Cornetto Enigma (+$2.00)</option>
        </select>
      </li>

      <li>Coffee:
        <select class="optionsCoffee" name="Coffee">
          <option value="Coffee01">Select Coffee</option>
          <option value="Coffee02">Cup of Joe (+$0.99)</option>
          <option value="Coffee03">Cappuccino (+$2.49)</option>
          <option value="Coffee04">Latte Macchiato (+$2.99)</option>
        </select>
      </li>

      <li>Computers:
        <select class="optionsComputers" name="Computers">
          <option value="Computer01">Select Computer</option>
          <option value="Computer02">Dell Inspiron 620 (+$449.99)</option>
          <option value="Computer03">HP Pavilion dv7t (+$949.99)</option>
          <option value="Computer04">iMac 27-inch 3.1GHz (+$1,999.00)</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>

    Total: <input class="totalAmount" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="0.00" />

  </fieldset>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        (function () {
            var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
                L = selects.length,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
                selects[i].setAttribute("onchange", "calcTotal();");
            }
        }());

        function calcTotal() {
            var icecream = [0.00, 1.85, 4.85, 2.00],
                coffee = [0.00, 0.99, 2.49, 2.99],
                computer = [0.00, 449.99, 949.99, 1999.00],
                total = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0],
                select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

            total.value = (icecream[select[0].selectedIndex] +
                coffee[select[1].selectedIndex] + 
                computer[select[2].selectedIndex]).toFixed(2);
        }
    //]]>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting IceCream01, IceCream02, etc and for others, consider putting the price. I think that would make it easier for you to calculate the total

```
      <li>Ice Cream:
        <select class="optionsIceCream" name="IceCream">
          <option value="0.0">Select Ice Cream</option>
          <option value="1.85">Solero Exotic (+$1.85)</option>
          <option value="4.85">Magnum Ecuador (+$4.85)</option>
          <option value="2.00">Cornetto Enigma (+$2.00)</option>
        </select>
      </li>
```

Using this pattern, you can simply get the selected value and add them up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer momo. Although I need a javascript that can do this without changing the existing attribute values or adding new attributes to the Option tag.

Comment: Yeap no problem. If you don't have a choice, then you should do what you need to do. But if you could change the code, you should consider changing that. It's not ideal to get the data from part of the text as you could not rely on them. I was just wondering what those values IceCream01, etc are used for and thought of suggesting the alternative. The answer from @Sjoerd should give you what you want

Comment: I have a code that creates these option lists, it also makes certain specific attributes, if I would change these the code wouldn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find the numerical part of the string, and then parseInt() it to get the number.

Comment: parseInt() will return an int. That is, parseInt('1.85') will return 1, not 1.85. Use the unary plus operator to convert a string to a number: +'1.85' will give 1.85.

Comment: I'm sorry, you can use either parseFloat() or Number() to convert it to number.

Answer (score 0):

You can match it with a regular expression:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\(\\+\\$([0-9.]*)\\)');
var match = re.exec('(+$1.85)');
return match[1];
```

This matches `(+$`, numbers, `)`. Escaping is done with double backslashes, `\\`. The numbers are put between parenthesis to indicate a group, which is returned in `match[1]`.

Comment: How do you send the result of this code to the inputbox, could you clarify this by using your code in the sample html above?